# "Unable to enumerate USB device" on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, 20.04

When I connect a particular USB device to my old laptop running Ubuntu 20.04, I see the following in `dmesg`:

```
[  101.184759] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[  101.221814] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[  101.363311] usb 2-1: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[  101.812806] usb 5-1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd
[  102.244741] usb 5-1: device not accepting address 3, error -71
[  102.376800] usb 5-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
[  102.800780] usb 5-1: device not accepting address 4, error -71
[  102.800859] usb usb5-port1: attempt power cycle
[  102.800880] usb usb5-port1: failed to disable port power
[  102.928784] usb 5-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using uhci_hcd
[  103.068802] usb 5-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  103.312783] usb 5-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  103.556792] usb 5-1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using uhci_hcd
[  103.696795] usb 5-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  103.948812] usb 5-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  104.056848] usb usb5-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

The device does not show up when I run `lsusb`.  This computer is running an up-to-date and relatively clean build of Ubuntu, with kernel 5.4.0-31.35-generic 5.4.34 (from `/proc/version_signature`).

As an experiment, I booted from a 18.04.4 live flash drive and connected the device again, and got this in `dmesg`:

```
[  302.308745] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[  302.469632] usb 2-1: config 1 interface 4 altsetting 0 bulk endpoint 0x4 has invalid maxpacket 64
[  302.469641] usb 2-1: config 1 interface 4 altsetting 0 bulk endpoint 0x85 has invalid maxpacket 64
[  302.470040] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0644, idProduct=802a, bcdDevice= 1.01
[  302.470047] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=12, Product=13, SerialNumber=0
[  302.470052] usb 2-1: Product: US-800
[  302.470057] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: TASCAM
```

The hardware configuration was the same for this test; same USB port on the laptop, same USB cable.  I think this pretty well rules out a hardware problem.  The running kernel was 5.3.0-28.30~18.04.1-generic 5.3.13 (from `/proc/version_signature`).

I don't see why this would matter, but the USB device is a Tascam US-800 audio interface.  The laptop is a 2007 MacBook.  I understand that this is an old laptop and that I may not ultimately be able to get the audio interface to work in Ubuntu, but it definitely won't work if it cannot even recognize the device and try to load the right driver.

Finally, the question: **how do I troubleshoot/isolate this problem?**

*Edit 6-3-20:*
I ran updates on the computer today and tested again. No change; still experiencing the same problem.  Kernel version (from `/proc/version_signature`) is now 5.4.0-33.37-generic 5.4.34

Comment: I have run into this problem several times in the last week. After 3 hours of using my session, all USB controllers just stop working. The only information I have are those error messages that I can see when I reboot. I am also using Ubuntu 20.04 and I didn't have this issue before with previous version. I found [this recent ticket](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202541) on kernel's bugzilla.

Comment: i am having the same issue with ubuntu 20.04, anyone please help !